# How to Write a Script to Set Local Security Settings?

Tags: windows-server-2008

For Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 7.

Is there a way to use powershell or other language to script Local Security Settings?  For example, add a local user to the "Create global objects" policy?

Also for modifying DCOM settings?

This is to be part of an install script for a legacy app that is being ported to Windows 7.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

The "official" method for automating the deployment of security settings is a combination of [Security Templates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772881(WS.10).aspx) and the [Secedit tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742472(WS.10).aspx) to apply the templates.

Programmatically setting DCOM permissions is a huge blind spot that Microsoft still hasn't addressed to my satisfaction. The "State of the Art" in setting DCOM permissions on remote computers, last I checked, is still to do registry merges. ([This unsupport DCOM permissions tool](http://www.myitforum.com/articles/11/view.asp?id=9323) might be helpful to you, too, but I've never used it and can't speak to its effectiveness.)

Comment: as you mentioned security templates won't help with dcom perms. It seems simpler to use 1 script to make the changes per app rather than creating templates and still require a script for reg merges.

Comment: It's all up to you. I'd use "Security Templates" because I think that would be easier for "the next person" to understand (assuming they're familiar with that functionality in the operating system, of course). DCOM permissions are an ugly, nasty swamp that Microsoft needs to "drain" in an officialy supported way.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've ever found is to review the registry entries created by this type of action and using either reg.exe (or the scripting language of your choice) to re-create the entries and reboot.  Of course once you export the registry entries you could also [convert them to ADM/ADMX files](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/8c703a2e-4685-4093-a1fc-dec107c53d13) to use group policy to push them out.